# C/Cygwin: Porting htoll() from macOS/unix to Windows Cygwin

Tags: c, windows, unix, networking, cygwin

I am poring my app from macOS platform to Windows platform (here it is Cygwin). I encounter problem with networking functions ntohll() and htonll() while ntohl()/htonl() and ntohs()/htons() seems to work correct

```
    /* LACK OF ntohll() function definition on Cygwin */
    // convert int64 from network to host representation
    *int64 = ntohll(network_int64);

    /* SEEMS TO WORK CORRECTLY */
    // convert int32 from network to host representation
    *int32 = ntohl(network_int32);
```

UPDATED: what about this?

```
uint64_t ntohll(uint64_t network_num64) {

    uint32_t network_num32[2];
    uint32_t host_num32[2];
    uint64_t host_num64;

    memcpy(network_num32, &network_num64, sizeof(network_num64));
    host_num32[0] = ntohl(network_num32[0]);
    host_num32[1] = ntohl(network_num32[1]);

    memcpy(&host_num64, host_num32, sizeof(host_num64));
    return host_num64;
}
```

and

```
uint64_t htonll(uint64_t host_num64) {

    uint32_t host_num32[2];
    uint32_t network_num32[2];
    uint64_t network_num64;

    memcpy(host_num32, &host_num64, sizeof(host_num64));
    network_num32[0] = htonl(host_num32[0]);
    network_num32[1] = htonl(host_num32[1]);

    memcpy(&network_num64, network_num32, sizeof(network_num64));
    return network_num64;
}
```

Comment: Hint: You can use `htonl` twice to create `htonll`.

Comment: Could you give me example? Should I split uint64_t number to 2 uint32_t numbers somehow?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: Are you sure?   How do you know in which order to use the two results?

Comment: Yeah this is the problem with the order of this two numbers ;/ I updated with this hint but I think it will not work correctly.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Assuming [`__BYTE_ORDER__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html) is also available.

Answer (score 0):

I have written my own htonll() and ntohll() functions that can solve the problem of endianness on Cygwin in the case of uint64_t (64 bit numbers). I think it should works but also want you to prove it really is a good solution.

I written following functions: 
1. isBigEndian() and isLittleEndian() - that check whether current host is using big or little endian 
2. Than I assume that Network Byte Order is Big Endian. So if on current host there is Little Endian I will need to swap endianness and if Big Endian than I just can use endianness received in htonll()/ntohll() param's number. 
3. I have written function that swaps endianness from big or little to little or big respectievely for 64-bit numbers, i.e. swapEndianness()

Here's all code:

```
bool isBigEndian() {
    int n = 1;
    // little endian if true
    if(*(char *)&n == 1) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool isLittleEndian() {
    return  !(isBigEndian());
}

uint64_t swapEndianness(uint64_t num) {

    uint64_t b0, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7;
    uint64_t swapped_num;

    b0 = (num & 0x00000000000000ff) << 56u;
    b1 = (num & 0x000000000000ff00) << 40u;
    b2 = (num & 0x0000000000ff0000) << 24u;
    b3 = (num & 0x00000000ff000000) << 8u;
    b4 = (num & 0x000000ff00000000) >> 8u;
    b5 = (num & 0x0000ff0000000000) >> 24u;
    b6 = (num & 0x00ff000000000000) >> 40u;
    b7 = (num & 0xff00000000000000) >> 56u;

    swapped_num = b0 | b1 | b2 | b3 | b4 | b5 | b6 | b7; 

    return swapped_num;
}

uint64_t htonll(uint64_t host_num64) {

    if(isLittleEndian()) {
        // swap little endian to big endian (network byte order)
        return swapEndianness(host_num64);
    }
    return host_num64;
}

uint64_t ntohll(uint64_t network_num64) {

    if(isLittleEndian()) {
        // swap big endian (network byte order) to little endian
        return swapEndianness(network_num64);
    }
    return network_num64;
}
```

I have also tested above code with:

```
static void test_swap_endianness(void) {

    uint64_t number = 0x1123456789ABCDEF;
    printf("hex number = 0x%" PRIx64 "\n", number);

    uint64_t swappedNumber = swapEndianness(number);
    printf("hex swapped number: 0x%" PRIx64 "\n", swappedNumber);
}
```

and achieve correct output while swapping endianness of uint64_t number:

```
=========== test_swap_endianness ==============
hex number = 0x1123456789abcdef
hex swapped number: 0xefcdab8967452311
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. This works by calling htonll and ntohll twice on the integer and swapping the order of the results. Note that this requires `endian.h`, because it checks the byte order to ensure compatibility with big-endian systems.

```c
#if __BYTE_ORDER == __BIG_ENDIAN
    #ifndef ntohll
        #define ntohll(num) (num)
    #endif
    #ifndef htonll
        #define htonll(num) (num)
    #endif
#else
    #ifndef ntohll
        #define ntohll(num) ({                                    \
            uint64_t _num = num;                                  \
            (((uint64_t) ntohl(_num)) << 32) | ntohl(_num >> 32); \
        })
    #endif
    #ifndef htonll
        #define htonll(num) ({                                    \
            uint64_t _num = num;                                  \
            (((uint64_t) htonl(_num)) << 32) | htonl(_num >> 32); \
        })
    #endif
#endif
```